# Form not saving data to model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC in order to build a blog. What I want is to save post comments to its corresponding place in the database but it does not work.

My post model is as follows:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate{get;set;}
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set;}
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 

}
```

My Comment model is as follows:

```
   public class Comment
    {

        [Key]
        public int CommentId { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PostId")]
        public virtual Post Post{get; set;}
        public string CommentCreateDate { get; set; }
        public string CommentUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string CommeterName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
        public bool Approved { get; set; }

    }
```

I have the following Action Methods:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateComment()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(int id, string name, string email, string txt, bool aproved = false)
    {

        Post post = GetPost(id);
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.Post = post;
        comment.CommentCreateDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        comment.CommeterName = name;
        comment.EmailAddress = email;
        comment.CommentText = txt;
        comment.Approved = aproved;
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();

        m_commentList.Add(comment);



        return RedirectToAction("CreateComment", new { id = id });

    }
```

And in my view I am trying this:

```
@model Blog.Models.Comment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateComment";
}

<h2>Create a Comment</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <fieldset>

            <legend>Enter Comment</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommeterName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CommeterName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommentText)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CommentText)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create comment" />
            </p>

        </fieldset>

    }
```

I get no exception but none of the data from the form is being saved. Only the data that is set in the action result, that is, CommentCreateDate and Approved.   I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have tried a second option which is to include the id of the comment in BeginForm() as follows:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new {id = Model.CommentId}))
{
    <fieldset>

        <legend>Enter Comment</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommeterName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CommeterName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommentText)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CommentText)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create comment" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>

}
```

This will give me a null reference exception even if I use the new keyword :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Why is this happening? Can anybody help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your action signature should be:

```
public ActionResult CreateComment(Comment model)
```

The names generated for the form fields will bind back to the properties of the *same* model class. There's no way for the framework to know, for example, that the `CommenterName` property should match up to the `name` parameter of the action.

Your second example makes very little sense - you're trying to write out the ID but you have never set one. In fact, you don't even pass a `Comment` to the view with the form, which is why you get a `NullReferenceException`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateComment()
{
    return View();
}
```

Also, you should be careful with what fields you expose to your models and actions. For example, a user could easily force their comment to be approved just by adding the following markup via their browser's development console:

```
<input type="hidden" name="approved" value="true" />
```

Anything that is either in your model properties or a parameter to your action *can be set by the user*.

An altogether better option would be to use a dedicated model class for the form:

```
public class CreateCommentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then to map this to your `Comment` in your action with:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateComment(CommentViewModel model)
{
    var comment = new Comment();
    comment.CommenterName = model.Name;
    // etc...
}
```

This prevents the user from being able to set things like `Approved` and `CreatedDate`.

Comment: Whatever you need it to be - I'm just trying to demonstrate a better way for you to do your model binding. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!! it was still necessary however to pass the id in the signature like this:  public ActionResult CreateComment(int ?id, CommentViewModel model)

Comment: No problem - please do go with a proper view model as per the second part of my answer though (if you haven't already).